# No module named "selenium/googletrans/tabula" when running script through cmd but works fine on idle?

Tags: python, selenium, cmd, python-idle

I have a list of python scripts which run perfectly fine through idle. However, when I run it through cmd I get various errors stating

No module named 'selenium',
,No module named 'googletrans'
,No module named 'tabula'

When I use pip install it says.
'Requirement already satisfied'

Also when I check pip list the above mentioned modules are there.

**sys.path**

**In cmd**

['', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\Documents\PC_scrape\Scraper', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\ C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python36.zip', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages']

**'I added the second and third item in the list**

**In idle**

['C:\Users\jay.haran\Documents\PC_scrape\Scraper', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\Documents\PC_scrape\Scraper', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\Documents\PC_scrape\Scraper\ C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python36.zip', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32', 'C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages']

**sys.version**
In both

In cmd and In idle = 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

**sys.executable**

In cmd = C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe

In idle = C:\Users\jay.haran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe

There are other modules installed such as bs4, xlrd, pandas that aren't causing any issues.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: The usual answer to this sort of question is that you have two python installations and the packages are only installed for one of them.  But you have already checked that.  I presume you are starting IDLE from an icon that runs pythonw.ex3.  What do you enter in the console?

Comment: I go to the folder the script is located in via cmd and I type Bundaberg.py. How can I fix this issue I have tried uninstalling python and reinstalling but it still persists.

Comment: The paths you show cmd include idlelib.  I think this is a mistake somewhere.  At the top of Bundaberg.py, put `import sys` followed by `for p in sys.path: print(p)`.  Run Bundaberg.py both from a command line and from IDLE,  Then replace the run-on lists above with the one file per line output, untouched by you.